# Falcon API - process respond after client gets it

Tags: python, gunicorn, falconframework

I have a `falcon` API (WSGI) that I wrote that needs to be as fast as possible.

At one part of the code I have the respond that I need to send to the client, but I have a datalake where I send all of responses + some more calculation results using kafka.
I want to separate the extra calculations + the send to kafka as the client does not need wait for it and it takes more time then I want it to.

Is there a way to do it in Falcon without handling the threads by myself like this:

```
class Compute(Thread):
    def __init__(self, request):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.request = request

    def run(self):
        print("start")
        time.sleep(5)
        print(self.request)
        print("done")


class FalconApi
    def on_post(self, request: falcon.Request, response: falcon.Response):
        thread_a = Compute(request.__copy__())
        thread_a.start()
```

I run the API using `gunicorn` so I thought maybe I could use the hook `post_request` but I can't seem to be able to get the response data in the hook. I also tried using `asyncio` but it seems like it does not like when I do use it because my app is WSGI.

My async code:

```
class FalconApi
        @staticmethod
    def http_post(response: falcon.Response) -> None:
        requests.post(consts.ENDPOINT, headers=response.headers, data=json.dumps(response.data))

    async def http_post_async(self, response: falcon.Response) -> None:
        await asyncio.to_thread(self.http_post, response)

    def on_post(self, request: falcon.Request, response: falcon.Response):
        self.http_post_async(response)
```

and the error that I got: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'http_post_async' was never awaited`

and when I changed it to:

```
    async def on_post(self, request: falcon.Request, response: falcon.Response):
        self.http_post_async(response)
```

I got: `TypeError: The <bound methodon_post of object at 0x7f7cf0c4ffd0>> responder must be a regular synchronous method to be used with a WSGI app.`

Comment: You can absolutely use `asyncio` with Falcon; it supports [ASGI](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/app.html#asgi-app) in addition to WSGI (but it's not clear why managing async coroutines is going to be any easier than managing threads). You could also investigate a task queue like [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) for a more structured solution.

Comment: @larsks I added the `asyncio` code that I tried to the question, maybe I did something wrong but it didn't work for me.
Why managing async coroutines is not easier than managing threads? If my service has tons of requests each request is managed on a new thread so if creating a new thread in each of those threads seems like it can overwhelm the service. while async does not create a new thread, so I thought it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing which worked for me.

I added a `gunicorn` hook `post_request` and I added the response I want to post process to the `falcon.request.env` attribute and then I extracted it in the hook.

My code looks something like:

api.py:

```
class FalconApi
    def on_post(self, request: falcon.Request, response: falcon.Response):
        response = <something>
        request.env['response'] = response
```

hooks.py:

```
def post_request(worker: SyncWorker, request: gunicorn.http.Request, environ: dict,
                 response: gunicorn.http.wsgi.Response) -> None:
    response = environ.get('response')
    if not response:
        logger.error(f'could not post process')
    PostProcessingRoute().post_process_response(response_body)
```

and then I run it using `gunicorn -c hooks.py`